# A Mazur manifold bounded by $\Sigma(2,3,13)$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds, kirby-calculus

Using Kirby calculus, Akbulut and Kirby first analyzed that the Brieskorn sphere $\Sigma(2,3,13)$ is diffeomorphic to the following link in their famous [paper](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ekirby/papers/Akbulut%20and%20Kirby%20-%20Mazur%20manifolds%20-%20MR0544597.pdf):

[image]

Then they switched the circles when they are **symmetric**. Next step is zero/dot change, which gives the desired Mazur type contractible 4-manifold.

What is this **symmetry** exactly? Does it preserve the isotopy type of the link? If yes, is this always true?

Comment: You probably mean to say the Mazur manifold has a presentation as surgery on the framed link in your diagram?  I have not read the paper but the symmetry you are refering to probably is a reference to the link being Brunnian, i.e. you can simultaneously turn the 0-framed component into a circle, which knots the -1-framed component.

Comment: Yes, the picture describes the surgery diagram of the boundary of the Mazur manifold up to diffeomorphism. If we are using the symmetry of a Brunnian link, then our observation is independent of framings, right? The only required condition is that they are all unknots.

Comment: Also related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372003/akbuluts-cork-involution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>I don't know where you took the picture from, but that link is *not* symmetric (and it likely does not describe the correct manifold).
Indeed, the 0-framed component of the link you drew is a trefoil: its diagram has three crossings and it is alternating. If you look at Figure 2 in Akbulut and Kirby's paper, the top crossing is the opposite than the one you drew here.</strike> **EDIT**: the diagram does represent the unknot... It's true that it's alternating, but it has a trivial Reidemeister-1 move available. Thanks Ryan for pointing this out. The rest of the answer is (as far as I can tell) still correct.

<strike>Once you switch those two crossings,</strike> Figure 2 in Kyle Hayden's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.06856) displays the symmetry Akbulut and Kirby refer to: the link is isotopic to a link that has a symmetric diagram, so the two components can be swapped. Note that it's not symmetric as a *framed* link. That is to say: this is not an instance of a *cork*, at least not in an obvious way (if you wanted an obvious cork, just put framing 0 on both components and you get what in the literature is called the Mazur cork).

As for the question

> is it always true?

I don't know what you mean exactly when you say "always". There is no reason why a link with two unknotted components should have an isotopy swapping the two components. The multi-variable Alexander polynomial, for instance, should be able to tell you that sometimes this cannot happen. It looks to me like the link [L9n19](http://katlas.org/wiki/L9n19) should give such an example.

Comment: Thanks! I used the original picture in their paper, it is the last diagram in Figure 23. To pass to the diagram appeared in Figure 2 for $\Sigma(2,3,13)$, they probably applied diffeomorphisms described in Proposition 2.

Comment: The 0-framed component is the unknot.

Comment: @RyanBudney: oops... this is a bit embarrassing :) I'll correct my answer.

Comment: No worries, mistakes happen.

Comment: @MarcoGolla The top crossing always makes me confused; this picture does not fit into the description in Figure 2 as you said. A similar but slightly different proof can be seen on pg. 27 in Akbulut's book "4-manifolds".